# How do I access the BinarySecurityToken and its contents in Sabre?

Tags: sabre

I need to retrieve the BinarySecurityToken to build another SOAP request HotelSearchRQ. I have successfully used TokenCreateRQ to create the token and the SOAP response, I get back success. However I cant access the header of the response which contains the BinarySecurityToken.

I have tried using:

```
SWSResponse response = rsp.getPayload();
```

I would have expected the payload to have included everything in the envelope but it's just the body see below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<sws:TokenCreateRS xmlns:sws="http://webservices.sabre.com" Version="1.0.0">
<sws:Success/>
</sws:TokenCreateRS>
```

How do I get the BinarySecurityToken?